# Bootstrap 4 carousel isn't working while switch tabs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a tabs and sub-tabs in my problem. In each sub-tab I want to run carousels. Carousel is working fine in 1st tab but when I switch to other tabs, it's not working. I don't have any idea where exactly the problem is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Parent-tab-1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab"
                    aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Parent-tab-2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">child-1_1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">child-1_2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">child-1_3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                                data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                                data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                                data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                                data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
                        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            </ol>
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                                data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button"
                                data-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">child-2_1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">child-2_2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab"
                            aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">child-2_2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel"
                        aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
                        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">
                        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">
                        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1400x600/?shoes" alt="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Can any one give a solution with examples?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: i have unique id in my original code but the problem occurs in bootstrap carousal .... u can see here ... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/carousel/